# Odds Asked Anew

Tags: probability

So for this wheel, if I have just one spin, then the **PROBABILITY** that I get purple is

[image: spin-once-eight-colors]

[image]

And that's 1 / 8.

(Where f is the number of favorable outcomes and n is the number of possible outcomes.)

The **ODDS** that I get purple are

1:7

odds(A) = f :u

(Where f is the number of favorable outcomes, and u is the number of unfavorable outcomes.)

Additionally, I could say I have a 12.5% probability of spinning a purple.

And, that, in most cases, I wouldn't describe the odds as **ANYTHING** other that 1:7 ("one to 7").

Am I right?

Comment: Your image shows nine distinct outcomes which are not equiprobable. This conflicts with the rest of your post, which assumes eight equiprobable outcomes.

Comment: Dark blue - 1 Light blue - 2 Green - 3 Yellow - 4 Orange - 5 Red - 6 Black - 7 Purple - 8.  I'm confused - 9?  Seems like 8?

Comment: There is a darker blue between black and purple.

Comment: Please see here: https://ibb.co/5KGf04v

Comment: There is a darker segment to the left of the slice numbered '7' in the picture you linked. Anyway, the segments don't all look the same size. Are you allowed to assume that they are all the same size and that there are 8 distinct color? Then your reasoning is correct. Otherwise it's incorrect as mentioned already